# How to fix swift 3 nested generic error

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

The code below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Jry.png

```
class BaseModel {

}

class BaseView<T: BaseModel> {

}

class BaseController<T: BaseView<BaseModel>> {

}

class MarketModel: BaseModel {

}

class InfoModel: BaseModel {

}

class MarketView: BaseView<MarketModel> {

}

class InfoView: BaseView<InfoModel> {

}

class MarketViewController: BaseController<MarketView> {

}

class InfoViewController: BaseController<InfoView> {

}
```

I got the error message like this

'BaseController' requires that 'MarketView' inherit from 'BaseView'

'BaseController' requires that 'InfoView' inherit from 'BaseView'

How can I fix this?

Comment: HI and welcome to SO - please edit the question to include all the necessary info. avoid links and pictures for test that can be copied

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I solve this error with the following code:

```
class BaseModel {

}

class BaseView<T: BaseModel> {

}

class BaseController<T, U: BaseView<T>> {

}

class MarketModel: BaseModel {

}

class InfoModel: BaseModel {

}

class MarketView: BaseView<MarketModel> {

}

class InfoView: BaseView<InfoModel> {

}

class MarketViewController: BaseController<MarketModel, MarketView> {

}

class InfoViewController: BaseController<InfoModel, InfoView> {

}
```